# i want to increment the number on a cell when date is updated on another cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have date in A1 and number in B1, similarly date in D1 and number in E1. i want b1 and e1 to increment by 1 number whenever value changes in A1 and D1 respectively. i want the same logic to be applied to all the rows ex (if something changes in a2 then b2 should be incremented by 1 number, if something is updated in a3 then b3 should be be incremented by 1 number. similarly if d2 is updated then e2 should be incremented by 1 number and if d3 is updated then e3 should be incremented by 1 number.

i have tried using this VBA code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value + 1
   Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Range("E1").Value = Range("E1").Value + 1
   Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
End Sub
```

but its only working for those particular cells when i try to put range in them, its not working.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure) post might also be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have excel available right now but try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim shAdd as string
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            shAdd = "B" & Target.Row
            Range(shAdd).Value = Range(shAdd).Value + 1
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            shAdd = "E" & Target.Row
            Range(shAdd).Value = Range(shAdd).Value + 1
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
End Sub
```

The reason it wasn't working for you is this line in your code `Intersect(Target, Range("A1"))` only refers to the cell `"A1"` and not the entire column.  By replacing that with `"A:A"` I'm referencing the entire column.  This checks to see if the `Target` was any cell in column **A**. 
 Additionally, to make sure that the right cell is incremented on the same row as the changed cell, I've used the `.Row` attribute of the `Target`.  Since your cell to increment will always be in column B or E, I just need to append the `Target`'s row to the column letter and pass that as a string to the `Range` function here

```
shAdd = "E" & Target.Row
Range(shAdd).Value = Range(shAdd).Value + 1
```

Comment: You are a savior. Thank you so Much for this, it works.